# How to create a windows to display a image in JAVA with simpleITK

Tags: java, itk

language:JAVA

paltform:eclipse

package: simpleITK 0.9.0

I want to create a windows to display dicom image,so I use the function:

```
SimpleITK.show(image);
```

However，the result is :

```
Exception thrown in SimpleITK show: ..\..\..\..\..\SimpleITK\Code\IO\src\sitkShow.cxx:463:
sitk::ERROR: Error in administrating child process: [参数错误]
```

the meaning of Chinese is Parameter error

I can get the size of image and patient's name but I can't dispaly the image.
Is there anything wrong with my code? here is my code:

```
String path = "dicom/8.dcm";
ImageFileReader reader = new ImageFileReader();
reader.setFileName(path);
Image image = reader.execute();
SimpleITK.show(image);
```

My English is not very good,but I really need your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed ImageJ?  That's the application SimpleITK uses to display images, by default.

If you have some other application you'd like to use to display images, you can use the SITK_SHOW_COMMAND environment variable.  Set SITK_SHOW_COMMAND to be the full path to you image display application.

Also, by default SimpleITK write out the image as a Nifti file, which is passed to the display application.  To write the image in some other format, you can use the SITK_SHOW_EXTENSION environment variable.  For instance, if you display application takes as input a PNG file, you would set SITK_SHOW_EXTENSION to be ".png".